# SQL Developer, substitution variable, dynamic creation, based on equation

Tags: sql, oracle, variables, oracle-sqldeveloper

I want to have a single parameter in my script for a year.

```
define YYYY = 2014;
```

then I want a 2nd parameter based on this one

```
YYYY2 = &&YYYY - 1;
```

i.e. it's 1 year earlier

But from the reading i've done so far this seems to be impossible.

Here's my attempt

```
define YYYY = 2014;
define YYYY2 = &&YYYY - 1;

select &&YYYY, &&YYYY2 from DUAL

select * from cb_enrolment2_&&YYYY;
select * from cb_enrolment2_&&YYYY2 ;
```

response for last line of code is :

```
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
00933. 00000 - "SQL command not properly ended"
*Cause: 
*Action: 
Error at Line: x Column: y
```

Comment: add a ; after the 3rd line

Answer (score 1):

That happens because you assign, literally, `2014 - 1` to `YYYY2`.

So:

```
select &&YYYY, &&YYYY2 from DUAL
```

turns into

```
select 2014, 2014 - 1 from DUAL
```

which is a valid query, but

```
select * from cb_enrolment2_&&YYYY2
```

turns into

```
select * from cb_enrolment2_2014 - 1
```

which gives you an error.

You can't do math directly on substitution variables, but you can select data from database into them, using `column` command with `new_value` argument. So, nothing stops you from selecting an arithmetical expression from `dual`:

```
define YYYY = 2014;
column dual_x new_value YYYY2;
select &&YYYY - 1 dual_x from dual;
```

`YYYY2` is created implicitly while executing `column` and `select`, so there's no need to `define` it.

SQLDeveloper uses dialect of SQL*Plus in its worksheet, see this for reference and more details on substitution variables: https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/entry/sqlplus_101_substitution_varia#2_5

Comment: Thanks. I think this may be very close to the solution however I continue to get the 'enter substitution variable' box popping up when i try to use the YYYY2 variable. Which is what I'm trying to avoid doing.

Comment: @ClancyBirrell that's strange. After three lines I've pasted above, I'm able to execute queries like `select &&YYYY2 from TABLENAME_&&YYYY;` just fine. Post the line where it throws the error, or amend your question to include full script up to error, please?

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. It's not an error. It's the SQL DEVELOPER popup window that requests a manual entry of the substitution variable value. SO I can't really cut and paste the error here as it's a popup. =`C

Comment: @ClancyBirrell well it prompts you at a certain line, right? Like I said earlier, I'm able to use the variable just fine without sqldev prompting for it, so post the script up to that line so I could try and reproduce that.

Comment: thanks for the nudge....here's the code                                                                 'define YYYY =2014;
column dual_x new_value YYYY2 ;
select &&YYYY - 1 dual_x from dual;
select * from cb_nsl_&&YYYY2 ;'    The popup occurs after the final line.

Comment: This is VERY weird because the exact same code works for me. SQLDeveloper even says what it substitutes in a script output window: `old:select * from cb_nsl_&&YYYY2
new:select * from cb_nsl_2013`... Perhaps your SQLDev version is older? I use 4.1.0

Comment: I'm using V4.1.1.19 :C

Comment: Then that might be a bug, sqldeveloper is rich with bugs, unfortunately. You can try posting this in https://community.oracle.com/community/database/developer-tools/sql_developer/content or reaching http://stackoverflow.com/users/1156452/thatjeffsmith I guess.

Comment: @thatjeffsmith Hi Jeff, at Timekiller's suggestion, I wonder if you have come across thisproblem and/or know how to overcome it? The nature of it is elaborated in the discussion comments between myself and Timekiller. Timekiller seems to think it's a bug in my current installed version of SQLDeveloper.

Comment: Tested it out in sqlplus...and the new variable adds mountains of whitespace in front.